# How to serve static content dynamically in Struts2

Tags: struts2, browser-cache

in Struts2 it is possible to serve static content like images, JS or CSS files by putting them into resources/static. From this point Struts2 takes care for serving them on HTTP request and everyone, especially my JSPs, are happy.

Now I have to retrieve all this static files from a DB; I get them as `byte[]`. The purpose is to exchange the files without redeploying the web application.

Do you have any suggestions how to serve them elegantly?
Can I overwrite e.g. some static resource provider? Alternatively, should I provide an action for that?
I'm mainly concerned about caching. Is there something else I should be concerned about?

Thanks in advance, any hint is appreciated! :)

Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an action to fetch the data from the database and then use the `stream` result type. The `stream` result will automatically handle setting the appropriate cache headers for the response (caching is turned on by default). You will need to provide the content type and the `InputStream`.

For details, check the Javadoc for [StreamResult](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StreamResult.html).

Comment: Well, stream result was a good start, but I did not get it working regarding caching by default. It never sent a 304 response. Had to check the "If-Modified-Since" header in the request and set the "Expires", "Last-Modified" and "Retry-After" headers in the response. When client's cache is still up to date, I'm sending a httpheader (304) result instead of a stream result. This way everything works smoothly!